# import_array segfaults when called from a dynamic library

Tags: python, c++, numpy, ctypes

The goal is to create a numpy array in c++ and access it in python.

The block of code below runs fine when run as a program.
However, if I use ctypes and run the function, it segfaults on _import_array call. Could someone tell me why this happens ?

```
#include "Python.h"
#include "numpy/arrayobject.h"
using namespace std;

extern "C"
PyObject* test_create_numpy() {
  Py_Initialize();
  _import_array();
  double* a = new double[1];
  a[0] = 1.0;
  npy_intp dims = {1};
  PyObject *Arr = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData( 1, &dims, PyArray_FLOAT64, a);
  return Arr;
}

int main() {
  test_create_numpy();
  return 0;
}
```

The python code used:

```
utils = cdll.LoadLibrary("test.dylib")
test_create_numpy = utils.test_create_numpy
test_create_numpy.restype = py_object
ret_vec = test_create_numpy()
print ret_vec
```

Comment: Use `utils = ctypes.PyDLL("test.dylib")` to avoid releasing the global interpreter lock.

Comment: Yup, that was the issue. Thanks! If you could post it as the answer, that would be great.